# show button based on a condition in Grails

Tags: grails

in the Grails application i need to add `Extend` button when a condition is true ,

Here is my GSP :

```
<table class="table table-hover  table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <g:sortableColumn property="adTitle"
                title="${message(code: 'ads.adTitle.label', default: 'Ad Title')}" />
                <g:sortableColumn property="adDetails"
                    title="${message(code: 'ads.adDetails.label', default: 'Ad Details')}" />

                    <g:sortableColumn property="duration"
                        title="${message(code: 'ads.duration.label', default: 'Duration')}" />
                        <g:sortableColumn property="dateCreated"
                            title="${message(code: 'ads.dateCreated.label', default: 'Creation Date')}" />
                            <g:sortableColumn property="durationDate"
                                title="${message(code: 'ads.durationDate.label', default: 'End Date')}" />

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <g:each in="${adsInstanceList}" status="i" var="adsInstance">
                                <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}" >
                                    <td><g:link action="show" id="${adsInstance.id}">
                                        ${fieldValue(bean: adsInstance, field: "adTitle")}
                                    </g:link></td>

                                    <td>
                                        ${fieldValue(bean: adsInstance, field: "adDetails")}
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        ${fieldValue(bean: adsInstance, field: "duration")}
                                    </td>

                                    <td><g:formatDate date="${adsInstance.dateCreated}" formatName='date.humanView' /></td>
                                        <td><g:formatDate date="${adsInstance.durationDate}" formatName='date.humanView' /></td>
                                            <td id="test"> </td>

                                        </tr>
<g:if
    test="${formatDate(formatName:'date.humanView',date:adsInstance.durationDate) == formatDate(formatName:'date.humanView',date:new Date()+1)}">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(
        function() {
            var add = $('<g:submitButton name="extendAd"   value="Extend"  />')

            $('#test').append(add)

            -
        });
    </script>
</g:if>
</g:each>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

as the below screenshot shows when the `Ad End date` is `12-9-2016` the `Extend` button should appears , but as you can see it is showing 3 times in the first row only although it supposed to be shown in first,second and third rows.

Am i missing something in my GSP code?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this without javascript:

```
<td id="test"> 
    <g:if test="${formatDate(formatName:'date.humanView',date:adsInstance.durationDate) == formatDate(formatName:'date.humanView',date:new Date()+1)}">
       <g:submitButton name="extendAd" value="Extend"  />
    </g:if>
</td>
```

If you want to do this with javascript, you cannot use an id (because id has to be unique) but a class:

```
<td class="test"></td>
```

...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
    function() {
        var add = $('<g:submitButton name="extendAd"   value="Extend"  />')

        $('.test').append(add)

    });
</script>
```

Comment: this solved the issue `<td id="test"> 
    <g:if test="${formatDate(formatName:'date.humanView',date:adsInstance.durationDate) == formatDate(formatName:'date.humanView',date:new Date()+1)}">
       <g:submitButton name="extendAd" value="Extend"  />
    </g:if>
</td>`